# How do you query WordPress post tags?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using 
     $project->post_title; 
to query WordPress post titles in a JSON export, and that seems to be working. How do I query the post tags? I tried
     $project->post_tags; 
and I tried 
     $project->the_tags; 
but neither of these seem to be working.

Comment: are you able to use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list get_the_tag_list()

Answer (score 1):

This function will do what you want : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
```